# Not able to retry the same request after refresh call in Anuglar

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am not able to retry the same request after the refresh call. I have tried `next.handle(updated_request)` but still, it is not running. Can you please help with this.

FYI: I have attached my code here. Please let me know, If I missed anything here.

```js
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this.presentLoading();
  const headerSettings = req.headers.keys().reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = req.headers.getAll(cur);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return fromPromise(this.storage.get('userdata')).pipe(mergeMap((token: any) => {
    if(token)
      headerSettings["Authorization"] = token.access_token;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings),
    newRequest = req.clone({ headers });
    return next.handle(newRequest)
      .pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              // token is expired refresh and try again
              if (err.status === 401) {
                if(token && token.refresh_token) {
                  this.login.refresh(token.refresh_token).subscribe((data: any) => {
                    if(data.data)
                      headerSettings["Authorization"] = data.data.access_token;
                    headers = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);
                    let retryRequest = newRequest.clone({ headers });
                    return next.handle(retryRequest);
                  });
                } else {
                  this.route.navigate(['/tabs/login']);
                }
              } else {
                return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
              }
          } else {
              return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
          }
      }));
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure as to why your inner subscription isn't triggering but I'd stab a guess that RxJS is cancelling it because it's in a disposable section of code.

`catchError` expects an `Observable` be returned, but you're not returning anything (TypeScript should warn about this, but it's slipped through the cracks for some reason).

The following is probably a better approach. The inner `Observable` is being subscribed to by `catchError` using `switchMap`.

```js
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.presentLoading();
    const headerSettings = req.headers.keys().reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = req.headers.getAll(cur);
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return fromPromise(this.storage.get('userdata')).pipe(mergeMap((token: any) => {
        if(token)
        headerSettings["Authorization"] = token.access_token;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings),
        newRequest = req.clone({ headers });
        return next.handle(newRequest)
        .pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                // token is expired refresh and try again
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    if(token && token.refresh_token) {
                    return this.login.refresh(token.refresh_token).pipe(
                        switchMap((data: any) => {
                        if (data.data)
                            headerSettings['Authorization'] =
                                data.data.access_token;
                        headers = new HttpHeaders(
                            headerSettings
                        );
                        let retryRequest = newRequest.clone({
                            headers,
                        });
                        return next.handle(retryRequest);
                    }));
                    } else {
                    this.route.navigate(['/tabs/login']);
                    }
                } else {
                    return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
                }
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
            }
        }));
    }))
}
```

Comment: Instead of `switchMap` I used `mergeMap` because `Observable` accepts `mergeMap`. It is working now. Thanks a lot for this timely answer

Comment: Great, glad it worked. I believe both `mergeMap` and `switchMap` will work in this scenario, but `switchMap` should have the added bonus of unsubscribing from the `login.refresh` observable once done with, and thus be a little more memory efficient. But perhaps I'm missing something - there's a lot going on. As a rule of thumb, you should *almost* never need two calls to `subscribe` for RxJs logic.